# MySQL query order the results in GROUP BY 3 Tables Count

Tags: php, mysql

I'm coding a listing system and I'm trying to get the posts ORDER by number of comments and votes FROM 2 tables.

```
Table1 : Lists => id, title, detail

Table2 : Votes => voteid, listid

Table3 : Comments => commentid, listid
```

WHERE MY Current query is

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zoo_leads 
LEFT JOIN Votes ON Lists.id=Votes.listid
LEFT JOIN Comments ON Lists.id=Comments.listid
GROUP BY Lists.id ORDER BY Comments.listid DESC LIMIT 10
```

it is showing me results perfectly but ORDER BY is Lists.id Instead of number of votes and comments

Comment: Maybe the problem is that there is no COUNT().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM   zoo_leads
       LEFT JOIN votes
         ON lists.id = votes.listid
       LEFT JOIN comments
         ON lists.id = comments.listid
GROUP  BY lists.id
ORDER  BY COUNT(votes.id) DESC,
          COUNT(comments.id) DESC
LIMIT  10
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have `ORDER BY Comments.listid` in your SQL statement.